# change image from path to embedded

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html image

```
<img src="/path/to/my/image.png" />
```

I want the same content,  but as an embedded image

```
<img src="data:image/png:base64/xyzafasfasfafasfafasfasag">
```

can I do this transformation easily with Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself:

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
// Create an empty canvas element
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;

// Copy the image contents to the canvas
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,img.width,img.height);

// Get the data-URL formatted image
// Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to guess the
// original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg" will re-encode the image.
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

return dataURL;//.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

html: `<img src="/path/..." id="image">`

js: `document.getElementById('image').src = 'data:image/png:base64/qweqwe...';`

Comment: no, I mean to transform the content of the path image to the corresponding binary code for data:image

Comment: oh
i don't think it's possible